# Notice: Undefined index: ($_FILES)

Tags: php, mysql

There are multiple questions[duplicates] about this same error but I can't find a solution in any of them. I`m trying to save an image in my local directory but 'Undefined index' keeps showing up. I´m a noob in php and stack overflow. I would really appreciate any of your help.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-push-5 image-div form-control">
      <div class="input-margin">
        <input type="file" name="imagenIngreso" class="filestyle" onchange="readURL(this);" data-buttonText="Subir Imagen" data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-size="nr" data-buttonBefore="false">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img class="image-preview" id="blah" src=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 submit-button">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" value="ingreso">Ingresar</button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
 // Previous Validations
 else if($_POST['submit'] == 'ingreso') {
    $fileName = $_FILES['imagenIngreso']['name']; // Line throwing error
    $uploadDirectory = "images/uploadedImages/Ingresos/";
    if($uploadedFileName!='') {
      $targetPath=time().$uploadedFileName;
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagenIngreso']['tmp_name'], $uploadDirectory.$targetPath)) {    
        $queryIngresos = "INSERT INTO ingresos (fechaIngreso, responsable, proyecto, items, imagePath) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$fechaEgreso','%d/%m/%Y'), '$responsable', '$proyectoIngreso', '$itemsArray', '$targetPath')"; 
        if(!mysqli_query($con, $queryEgresos)) {
          echo "Error while uploading file";
          die('Error :'.mysqli_error($con));
        } else {
          echo 'Upload done';
          exit();
        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: Check the PHP configuration `file_uploads` is enabled

Comment: add `var_dump($_FILES);` looks like noting is being uploaded

Comment: I checked and its enabled. I am uploading a file with the same code(different variables) just above this code so I don't understand why shouldn't be working.

Comment: If file isn't submit, the variable won't exist `$fileName = isset($_FILES['imagenIngreso']) ?  $_FILES['imagenIngreso']['name'] : '';`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your advice tadman! I had no clue that it was so dangerous. I will implement parameterised queries and bind_param to my code.

Comment: Having the same issue with your code Sylwit. I truly don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also find what error are you getting using the Error Codes available.
Put this and make a try.

```
<?php
if($_FILES['userfile']['error']) {
  // handle the error
} else {
  // process
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Naresh! I already changed it several times as you advised but nothing changed.

Comment: Just checked and it worked! Found my mistake and solved it!

Comment: Fine credits to you.:) Can you comment here what mistake have you done so that it will be useful for someone who gets the same error the other time... Rock on :)